# How to insert dynamic fields into a temporary table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Table structure is like this

```
NAME | 1-10-2014 | 2-10-2014 |

AAA  |  100      | 200

BBB  |  _        | 150
```

where dates are dynamic fields..  how to insert the result table into a temporary table where fields are dynamic? is it possible to insert into a new temporary table where fields are unknown?.

Comment: need to use dynamic query to create or alter table in run time. Or you can declare variable table in run time. But in my opinion it is not good when you maintain such table, try to simplify it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Redesign your table so the problem disappears:

Table structure becomes:

```
NAME | RECORDDATE | VALUE |

AAA  |  1-10-2014| 100
AAA  |  2-10-2014| 200
BBB  |  2-10-2014| 150
```

No problem with null values, either.

Comment: cant do that. pivoted the actual table to get the result like this. The actual table structure was same as u said .

Comment: Well I don't know why you're pivoting and what you're trying to do with the output. Perhaps you can describe what you're actually trying to achieve?